# strict mode not working in Flash IDE, no warning for 'no type declaraion'

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, warnings

I'm trying to get warnings to show up for:

```
var foo = 0;
```

for no type declaration.  in Advanced Actionscript 3.0 Settings, I have Strict Mode and Warnings Mode checked. Is there something I'm missing?

Oddly, duplicate variable definitions DO show up as warnings.

Flash Version 11.5.0.325   Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The declaration itself isn't going to throw an error. When you don't declare the type in a variable definition, you're not eliminating type checking you're just deferring it to runtime instead of compile time, even with strict mode enabled. Here is some example code like yours:

```
function typeTest(xParam:Array) 
{ 
    trace(xParam); 
} 
var myNum = 3; 
typeTest(myNum);  
// run-time error in ActionScript 3.0
```

That will still compile even in strict mode. The idea behind strict mode is so that you can take advantage of Actionscript 3's strict-typing abilities while writing your code and therefore catch more errors during compile time instead of runtime. If you don't use those abilities (by not strictly typing your variables in code) then it's useless to you. See the following link for complete documentation on this issue:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f8a.html